# How to get User Name from External Login in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, google-signin

I have set up an external login (Google) in my ASP.NET Core application. I am finding it hard to get the User Name / Email after login. I can see the email stored in AspNetUsers table But I don't see User Name anywhere.

I searched over and found this code:

```
var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

But this is giving me userId as is present in table AspNetUsers. `ClaimTypes.Email` returns null but the value is present in table (probably this email is something else). I want to fetch User Name and User Email. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to SignInManager or can you inject it? If yes, then this is how you would access user id (username), email, first & last name:

```
public class MyController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

    public MyController (
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
    )
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;        
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(){
    ExternalLoginInfo info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    string userId = info.Principal.GetUserId()
    string email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    string FirstName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.GivenName) ?? info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
    string LastName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Surname);
    }
}
```

GetUserId extension:

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static string GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
            return null; //throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));

        string ret = "";

        try
        {
            ret = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {                
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.What you are saying, is already happening in AccountController. But the problem is that there is No GetUserId method. There are properties in ClaimTypes as Email, GivenName and Surname but they are all null.

Comment: Are you using GetExternalLoginInfoAsync to retrieve ExternalLoginInfo? `ExternalLoginInfo info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

Comment: Yes, that's what 'info' object is.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that GetUserId is my own extension, use principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value; instead, or see my code for GetUserId.

Comment: I was missing this Scope = {"email", "profile"}  in my StartUp.cs and after adding that, I can see Name (i.e. user name) in 'info' present in Account controller under ExternalLoginCallback method. I tried your code in my other controller and it is still Not giving me user name. I want to have user name in my other controller. I am trying to figure out how to do that now.

Comment: Once the user is logged in, shouldn’t you be able to use `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value` ?

Comment: There are a couple of things here: When we first login there is a confirmation to register and that calls ExternalLoginConfirmation method in AccountController. This method uses email id as UserName and then this email id is actually saved in the AspNetUsers table as Name. I had to change that to pass name as UserName and then my desired 'name' is saved to database. Then I picked that name in my other controller as var name = this.User.Identity.Name; <- this user is from AspNetUsers table and I get my saved name.